# How to create a new list that is combination of 2 different lists elements without repetition?

Tags: python, random, iteration, combinations

I am trying to create a canvas that has 2 stimulis. Please note that stimuli lists can be longer.

```
sti1 = ["death", "pain"]
sti2 = ["glass", "book"]
```

These stimulis will shown like this:

frame 1: death - book  /  frame 2: glass - pain

**But they must shuffle correctly. I mean if there is a "death x book" combination, there must not be another one. Also, all combinations must be shown. Also, all frames must contain one word from sti1 and one word from sti2.**

Here is what I thought:

1. create a combination list that contains all the combinations.
2. use for loop to itarate.

If there is another solution than creating a combination list and iterate it, I am open to new things.

**I tried:**
random.choice
itertools.permutations
itertools.combinations (most close answer but this just can combine 1 list like sti1)

Expected result: 
combination_list = [(death, glass), (death, book), (pain, glass), (pain, book)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
list(product(sti1,sti2))
[('death', 'glass'), ('death', 'book'), ('pain', 'glass'), ('pain', 'book')]
```